# Copy database wizard - any change in lsn number of source database

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

After Copy database wizard - database restore in another server . Any change in LSN number of source database . is it same as copy only backup?

Answer (score 0):

One method which you can choose will use the SMO programming tools.  The other method which results in the source database going offline is detach/attach.  Neither of these will affect backups or LSN's.

Comment: thanks for the information . If i select the 'use the sql management object method ' 
is it use copy only backup mechanism .. ? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that will use a programming methodology called SMO/SQL Management Objects which allows a program (SQL Server in this case) to operate on SQL objects, in this case, the tables to be moved.  So the wizard is the program which takes advantage of these programming tools to move the objects to the new database.  The other method available uses Detach/Attach.